# MVC 5 Ajax.ActionLink retorna resultado, mas não renderiza no DOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, razor

Senhores, Estou tendo problemas em exibir uma lista de resultados na minha view.

A ideia é, ao clicar em um valor de um dropdown, eu faço uma consulta assíncrona para popular o dropdown seguinte. 
Eu consulto o controller pelo método Ajax.ActionLink, por que não quero recarregar a página, ou exibir o id na url:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

                            int count_pai = 0;

                            while (count_pai < LPPai.Count)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    @Ajax.ActionLink(LPPai[count_pai].valor, "AbrirChamado", new { id_pai = LPPai[count_pai].id }, null, new AjaxOptions()
                               {
                                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                                   UpdateTargetId = "dropdown_menu_problemas_filho",
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                               })
                                </li>

                                count_pai++;
                            }
                        }

</ul>
```

Então ao clicar em um elemento "li", eu envio o id do elemento para o controller e retorno o resultado da busca para o DOM alvo "dropdown_menu_problemas_filho".

O retorno da busca deve ser renderizado no elemento abaixo:

```
<ul id="dropdown_menu_problemas_filho" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

                        @if (LPFilho != null)
                        {
                            int count_filho = 0;

                            while (count_filho < LPFilho.Count)
                            {
                                <li>@LPFilho[count_filho].valor</li>

                                count_filho++;
                            }
                        }
</ul>
```

E debugando a view pelo razor, a lista realmente esta populada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo bem. O problema, é que depois disso, nada acontece! Nenhum valor é renderizado no DOM, mesmo não acontecendo erro algum, e o loop terminando sem problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tentei exibir os valores com @Html.DisplayText, colocar só o @LPFilho[count_filho].valor sem tags, e tudo mais! Nada funciona.

Alguém faz ideia do porque os valores não são renderizados? Existe meio melhor (ou mais correto) de cumprir essa tarefa? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

nao sei que js importaste.. mas exprimenta instalar o jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

procura no Nuget manager:
"Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" procura pela ultima versão.

Comment: Ola amigo, então, já estou usando o jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, e o jquery.validate.min.js. Em outra página eu uso o Ajax.BeginForm sem problemas.